# Get sales of products by week wise as week1,week2, week3, week4

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, mysql, sql

I have a requirement to make a sales report like this:

```
Product Name         First Week   Second Week  Third Week
   a                      12            6           2
   b                       0            0           4 
   c                       0            3           0
```

For this I made a function which returns sku and sum(qty_ordered) like

```
   $query = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection');
   $query->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
    ->columns(array('sku','qty_ordered'))
    ->where(new Zend_Db_Expr('created_at BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND NOW()'))
    ->group(array('sku'));
```

sql query for the above is:

```
SELECTmain_table.sku,main_table.qty_ordered, SUM(main_table.qty_ordered) ASweek1FROMsales_flat_order_itemASmain_tableWHERE (created_at BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND NOW()) GROUP BYsku;
```

But the above returns for only 1 week. If I change the `created_at BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND NOW()` to `created_at BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 2 WEEK AND NOW()` then it returns 2 weeks sales.. But I want the result as shown in the above format. So how can I customize this. Help me on this.

Comment: You should be able to group by WEEK(created_at) I believe, and then just make sure that your WHERE includes the range you're looking for (i.e. 3 weeks to now)

Comment: Douglas, you should post this as an answer!

Comment: But how can I get data of another two columns ie., week2 and week3?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in my comment, you should be able to use the WEEK(created_at) query to find this.  So (untested) but along the lines of:

```
$numberOfWeeks = 3;

$query = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection');
$query->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
->columns(array('created_at','sku','qty_ordered'))
->where(new Zend_Db_Expr('created_at BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL '.$numberOfWeeks.' WEEK AND NOW()'))
->group(new Zend_Db_Expr('WEEK(created_at)'));
```

This should then return something like the following:

```
2014-03-15   100
2014-03-08   90
2014-03-01   110
```

The first column is the week starting date, the second is the amount sold in that week.

You can iterate through this to produce a table view of the data where required.